# Adding a new random value to an input and then asserting that value has been updated in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am working with a dashboard that has a bunch of inputs for data. The user has the ability to edit any of the input field data and I am trying to test that functionality.

The trouble I am running into is that if I have a function `generateRandomString()` to give my edits new, individual data, how can I check if that value has been properly passed/updated?

With the code below I can't very well do my `.contains()` check and run the same function because it will be different.

Is there anyway to capture whatever the function has generated and then save it so I can assert change on the `.contains()` check?

Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

```
cy.get('[data-cy=station-form-name]')
      .click()
      .clear()
      .type(generateRandomString())
cy.get('button:contains("Create")').click()
// check if the name has been updated
cy.get('[data-cy=station-details-name]').contains(generateRandomString())
```

Comment: Are you looking to generate one random string and then using it for the code above or are you looking to generate two random strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the random string value in a Cypress environment variable, and reference that later.

```js
// generateRandomString function
const generateRandomString = () => {
// code to generate string
Cypress.env('randomString', myRandomString)
return myRandomString
}

// Cypress test
cy.get('[data-cy=station-form-name]')
      .click()
      .clear()
      .type(generateRandomString())
cy.get('button:contains("Create")').click()
// check if the name has been updated
cy.get('[data-cy=station-details-name]').contains(Cypress.env('randomString'))
```

If going this route, you'd probably want to add something to the beforeEach or afterEach that clears that environment variable.

Comment: This is a really neat approach! It also works really well!
Last question is where exactly in the `beforeEach` do you clear the enviornment variable?
I'm a bit confused on how you would write this. If I write my beforeEach like below, I get an error saying that `generateRandomString is not defined` ::::::
`beforeEach(() => {
    const generateRandomString = () => {
      let myRandomString =
        Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 7) +
        Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 7)

      Cypress.env('randomString', myRandomString)
      return myRandomString
    }
  })`

Comment: Adding `generateRandomString` to your beforeEach scopes the function to that block. So trying to use the function later in your tests would not work. You'd need to define the function elsewhere, and in your beforeEach you could just do `Cypress.env('randomString', undefined);`

Comment: Gotcha! So up until now I've been defining all of my variables just under the describe line of the test. Are you saying I should put that `generateRandomString` in my helpers file and import it in so I can get it out of my describe function?

Comment: So importing it and then doing the `Cypress.env('randomString', undefined)` in the `beforeEach` now throws the error `cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: undefined`. Sorry for all of this back and forth, but I'm so close to getting this working finally!

Comment: Re: putting `generateRandomString` in helpers - yes! The error message in the second suggests you're passing in `undefined` to the `cy.type()` command -- is it possible that `generateRandomString()` returns `undefined`?

Comment: For some reason just importing it and not changing the rest causes the error. Do I need to call it in the initial describe section or in the beforeEach with the `beforeEach(() => {
    Cypress.env('randomString', undefined)
  })` that I have already? 

My actual test hasn't changed syntax either, so perhaps that's the problem? `cy.get('[data-cy=input-field]')
      .eq(0).click().clear().type(generateRandomString())`

Thanks for the comments so far! I really appreciate it:D

Comment: Hmm... no, I think how you have it set should work. Can you try logging what the `generateRandomString()` return is before the function actually returns and make sure that isn't `undefined`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244083/discussion-between-lovelyandy-and-agoff).

Answer (score 7):

Just generate the string first

```js
const myString = generateRandomString()

cy.get('[data-cy=station-form-name]')
      .click()
      .clear()
      .type(myString)
cy.get('button:contains("Create")').click()
// check if the name has been updated
cy.get('[data-cy=station-details-name]').contains(myString)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one easy way to use a random string:

const workflowname = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,7)

cy.get('.undefined > .Input-module__box___BkvHA > input').clear().type(workflowname)

Answer (score 1):

You can use faker.js to generate random data.

1. To install use the command `npm install @faker-js/faker --save-dev`.
2. Your code should look like this:

```js
const faker = require('faker')

describe('Test Suite', () => {

  it('Test Case', () => {
    var randomNumber = faker.random.number()
    cy.get('[data-cy=station-form-name]').click().clear().type(randomNumber)
    cy.get('button:contains("Create")').click()
    // check if the name has been updated
    cy.get('[data-cy=station-details-name]').contains(randomNumber)
  })
})
```

For the above example, I have chosen random numbers, but if you want you can get other random things as well from this [list](https://github.com/faker-js/faker#api).

Comment: Thanks again for the comment, Ill try this out now!